# Estimating Pi with coprime probability efficiently

Tags: python, probability

All,

I'm not a great Python programmer, but I always like to learn. So, after watching [Matt Parker's latest Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZBhSi_PwHU&list=WL&index=11) I figured I'd give it a go. And in just a little bit, I have a program which does it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division
from fractions import gcd
from random import sample
from math import sqrt

NUMSAMPLES=10000

list1 = sample(xrange(1000000),NUMSAMPLES)
list2 = sample(xrange(1000000),NUMSAMPLES)

counter = 0

for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
    if gcd(i,j) == 1:
        counter += 1

prob_coprime = counter/NUMSAMPLES
pi_estimate = sqrt(6/prob_coprime)
print "Estimate of pi: ", pi_estimate
```

And this works. Huzzah! But, my guess is this is nowhere near the most efficient way to do it (I'm a Fortran programmer by trade so I think in loops). I'm sure there's a much better way to do that counter loop as I notice as NUMSAMPLES increases, this code takes longer.

And, probably, my list making is a memory hog as well. Perhaps a way with generators or something to just create i,j as needed?

So help this old man learn: what is/are the better, efficient Python ways of doing this?

Comment: Why are you still using Python 2? Why not 3.6? `fractions.gcd` is buggy. Use `math.gcd` instead.

Comment: And take a look at numpy: http://www.numpy.org/

Comment: I used 2.7 because the laptop I have at home uses Macports and the python and ipython I have installed are 2.7 based. I am sorry about that. I did not want to rebuild all the packages on my Mac for a quick problem. And, since I had 2.7 handy, all I can use is fractions.gcd since math.gcd is only 3 based. As for numpy, I do know it but I wasn't thinking this problem was really array based. I'm thinking more of a map, zip, reduce, generator...some Pythonic way to make the loop more efficient.